# Update figure plotted by matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to update an `imshow()` figure packed in `tkinter`. Here's a code example:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
import random

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


def get_data():
    return [[random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)], [random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)]]


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.figureCanvas = FigureCanvas(self.window)
        self.button = tk.Button(window, text="Update", command=self._button_command)
        self.button.pack()
        self._pack_figure()

    def _button_command(self):
        self.figureCanvas.data = get_data()
        self.figureCanvas.plot()

    def _pack_figure(self):
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figureCanvas.figure, master=self.window)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        canvas.draw()


class FigureCanvas:
    data = []

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self._create_plot_object()

    def _create_plot_object(self):
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot_object = self.axes.imshow([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

    def update(self):
        self.plot_object.set_data(self.data)


_window = tk.Tk()
_window.title("Snapshot")
start = MainWindow(_window)
_window.mainloop()
```

It plots the first image `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]` fine, but it doesn't re-draw after the image data has updated by `plot_object.set_data(self.data)`

## Update

I have tried calling the following functions under `FigureCanvas.update()`:

```
matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase(self.figure).draw_idle()
self.axes.redraw_in_frame()
```

Comment: "*it doesn't re-draw*" - because you didn't ask it to redraw. `self.figureCanvas.draw_idle()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am aware that I need to call some "re-draw" function, but I can't find one for figures not plotted with `pyplot`. `draw_idle()` only works with `pyplot`. See my update please.

Comment: Oh I missed the fact that what you call `FigureCanvas` is not actually a canvas. `draw_idle()` works with any *true* canvas. In particular it works for pyplot figure canvasses as well as custom ones.

Comment: Never mind. I sorted it myself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I tried many different things and then realised it was the canvas containing the `Figure` needs "re-draw". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct version of the code could look like this. I got rid of the false FigureCanvas and put everything in one class (sure you can use different classes, but don't name them confusingly). Also several other issues are fixed here (e.g. not calling the callback, supplying min and max color values).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk

def get_data():
    return np.random.randint(1,100,size=(2,2))

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.button = tk.Button(window, text="Update", command=self._button_command ) 
        self.button.pack()
        self._pack_figure()
        self._create_plot_object()

    def _button_command(self):
        self.data = get_data()
        self.plot()

    def _pack_figure(self):
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self.window)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    def _create_plot_object(self):
        axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot_object = axes.imshow([[0, 0], [0, 0]], vmin=0, vmax=100)

    def plot(self):
        self.plot_object.set_data(self.data)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

_window = tk.Tk()
_window.title("Snapshot")
start = MainWindow(_window)
_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. I just picked up Python yesterday, still learning hard :D. This works great! Would you mind clarifying why `vmin` and `vmax` are essential?

Comment: If initially the plot contains only zeros, it's not clear what color 100 should take. If initially your plot contained zeros and ones, 0 would be blue, 1 would be yellow and 100 would still be yellow, because it's larger than the maximum initial value. Hence it's important to clarify from the start which values are expected.